# Android : Theme.Holo VS Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android, themes, android-holo-everywhere, snackbar

I use "**@android:style/Theme.Holo**" as my game's theme :

[image]

But to be able to set up a snackbar widget, I have no choice but using "**@style/Theme.AppCompat**", otherwise I get this error message :

```
You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library
```

The problem is that the "**@style/Theme.AppCompat**" is visually quite different :

[image]

What could I do to stay with the same visual as "**@android:style/Theme.Holo**", but in the same time be able to use a snackbar widget?

EDIT
With the Yoann Hercouet's solution, here is the result :

[image]

What is missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally found the solution :

**AndroidManifest.xml** :

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
    ...
```

**MyDialog.java** :

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog));
```

Instead of :

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your app theme by changing the default style for dialogs:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog</item>
</style>
```

**EDIT**:

Not sure why it doesn't change anything, it worked on my app, maybe try this other way and create a custom style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/myAlertDialogStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="myAlertDialogStyle" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: Nothing changed, the theme remains gray, including the dialogs.

Comment: It is weird, you must remove any style that you applied on the dialog itself, this change will affect all the dialogs.

Comment: I did not assign any other style. But if I could just darken a bit the dialog & snackbar backgrounds, it would be perfect.

Comment: I found a problem, the AppTheme is well applied, but "item name="alertDialogTheme"" does not affect the dialog's visual.

Comment: I fixed this by importing android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog instead of import android.app.AlertDialog.

Comment: I added in case another way but the result should actually be the same.

Comment: Thank You Yoann. I uploaded the result. What is missing?

Comment: @Denis I got the same problem with the buttons, still taking the Material style, I guess you will have to change the buttons style in `myAlertDialogStyle`

Comment: Ok, no problem. But  what about the title?

Comment: Is it possible to assign the AppCompat Theme to the snackbar only? That way, it will solve all the problems at once.

Comment: Snackbar is meant to be used on Material so not sure how to achieve that, for the title how do you display it? You use the default `setTitle` method?

Comment: I use it, but like you can see on the printscreen, it is displayed on the wrong place.

Comment: I think you will have to also check and change the styles `windowTitleStyle ` and `buttonBarStyle ` :-/